# I tried to match the sound of this song but it sounds very different, what am I missing?

Tags: mixing, mastering

I originally asked this question in the Music stackexchange, but they suggested I ask it here, so here it goes.

I'm an amateur music producer, I have little experience.

I tried to create a cover of "Beneath the Mask" from the OST of the game Persona 5, and match the sound as closely as possible.

Here's a sample of my mix, the intro:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/p1k6nk6zhwo26if/Cover.ogg

And here's the same portion of the original I'm trying to match:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/loadpmet6nynal1/Original.ogg

As far as I hear, I got all the notes right, the EQing on the single instruments sounds pretty spot on to me and the spectrum of my mix looks very similar to the original; the panning sounds relatively similar, the volume levels sound good to me, after a bit of pain even the drums are not too far off.

There's something different about the EPiano, but I can't put my finger on what. Also the little guitar arpeggio has a very different sound that I don't know how to recreate, but I believe that's not the reason for the stark difference in sound.

I even put a bit of saturation and compression/limiting on the end result, and while it helps the mix sound better, the final mix still sounds very different from the original, but I can't figure out what to change to match the sound.

I feel like the original mix sounds "fuller", but without sounding muddy. I tried various combinations of mixing, panning and EQing but I can't achieve this combination.

I'm at my wit's end. What am I missing?

In case you want analyze more in-depth, here's my stems (in ogg format, and without the master effects):

http://www.mediafire.com/file/bvhowyn1jmyhzmx/BTM_-EP.ogg http://www.mediafire.com/file/ffbd0rqax71pfha/BTM-Bass.ogg http://www.mediafire.com/file/quxi1nhfin1jp81/BTM-Drums.ogg http://www.mediafire.com/file/c6rfo88ca22fa6c/BTM-_Guitar_Chords.ogg http://www.mediafire.com/file/c5lrpa2fzfwvi8l/BTM_-_Guitar_Arp.ogg

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the sustain pedal on the epiano. Original has a sustain pedal down on the epiano and the cover is missing the sustain.

The original is a little more compressed and has a little more 'room' than the cover.

Main issue though is the 'sustain' which is missing from the epiano.

Good try though - pretty close!